# Remote validation with a select input in MVC CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity

Hy everyone and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I'm working on a MVC CORE website and I'm try to add the remote validation with Entity Framework on a select input.

Unfortunately it seems to doesn't work... Here is my code :

HTML SELECT -->

```
<select asp-for="IDSociety" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListOfSociety,"ID", "Name"))"></select>
```

C# ViewModel -->

```
[Remote("VerifyNameService", "Parameter", AdditionalFields = "ServiceName", ErrorMessage = "Ce nom de service existe déjà pour cette société !")]
 public int IDSociety { get; set; }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you give some more information on how "doesn't work" looks like? Error Message, unexpected behavior...

Comment: Hi, 

You right I should have explicit this before ! 

The VerifyNameService method is not called when I change the value of the select. 

I Did the exact same method for a text field and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have your arguments backwards. It's trying to call the *action* named `VerifyNameService` on the *controller* named `Parameter`.

Here are the constructors for the `RemoteAttribute` in Core:

```
public RemoteAttribute(string routeName);
public RemoteAttribute(string action, string controller);
public RemoteAttribute(string action, string controller, string areaName);
```

Comment: Hi, 
Yes it's the right arguments, the action is VerifyNameService and the controller is Parameter.
Finally I had to use Jquery to make it work. but thank you for taking the time to answer my request.